# How to combine data in rows into a new column and into a new data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that has multiple entries on the same day with a TSS score.

```
    athlete    workoutday   tss
1  Athlete_1   2020-03-20   30
2  Athlete_1   2020-03-20   21
3  Athlete_1   2020-03-20   64
```

I would like some help in knowing how to combine the tss scores into into a new column and be put into a new data frame so that there is only 1 entry for each athlete.

for example

```
    athlete    workoutday   tss
1  Athlete_1   2020-03-20   115
2  
3
```

Cheers

Comment: `df %>% group_by(athlete, workoutday) %>% summarise(tss = sum(tss))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT Athlete_1,workoutday, (select SUM(tss) from your_table where athlete='Athlete_1') 
 as tss
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY Athlete_1;